# Is there a browser-side validation passed event I can listen for?

Tags: forms, javascript

Is there a JS event that my own custom code can listen for to determine that client-side / browser validation of a form has passed?

i.e. That no messages like this have occurred: "Please fill in this field" because a field was empty.

[image: Please fill in this field]

If there such an event that can be listened to then my own JS could handle the POST submission and then replace the form with a thank you message, in-situ / in place on the same page.

What I don't want to do is have my code run whether the form submission input by the user is valid or not. In other words I don't want to display a thank you message if they've not given valid data. That's why I need an event to say validation passed.

This to me is a better solution to say "thank you" rather than redirecting to content that can itself be indexed and accessed "outside" of the form submit situation, even if a module like rabbit_hole is used.

Looking for a Drupal 8 or 9 solution for myself but tagged with 7 to encourage answers for those who also might want an answer but for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal doesn't have a browser-side validation framework as it does with the back-end form validation handlers. The "Please fill..." message is the browser enforcing the `required` property.

If you'd like to hook into those validation events, you can bind event listeners on specific form elements for `invalid` events. If you want to take action on a submit click, the `checkValidity()` method can be executed on form field DOM objects.

See the MDN docs on the [constraint validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation) for more info.